# Email content showing in email preview but not in message itself - Google Apps Script MailApp

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to make a script that emails a table from Google Sheets. I pass the content to the HTML file, and fetch it back from the HTML file without issue. (The HTML table code displays in the console log.) The MailApp seems to run fine. When I go to my email, everything looks right (EVEN the preview) but the email itself shows no content...

Can someone explain to me what's happening?

[image: This is a sample that shows the preview text.]
[image: This is a sample that shows that same email, but with no content.]

Here's my code. Forgive my notes, they're for people who know even less than I do.

```js
  console.log("");                                      // The console log runs parallel to execution, for debugging. This is just a spacer, it makes the console log easier to read. 
  console.log("");
  console.log("// BEGIN EXECUTION //");                 // This is also a console log, it tells me that the script started running. 
  
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();                    // This script is "bound" to the spreadsheet, but we still need to tell the script what spreadsheet we're talking about
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Automated WeeklyScheduleToVolunteers"); // This directs the script to the right "tab" in the spreadsheet. This also means if you rename the tab, the script stops working. 
  
  console.log("Spreadsheet identified");                // See above, I'll stop commenting on the "just a notification"-type logs.
  
  var target_date = sheet.getRange("G2").getDisplayValue(); // This gets the G2 value, which the spreadsheet produces for the next service. 
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();                          // This finds the last row of the sheet with data in it.
  var tableRangeValues = sheet.getRange(5,4,lr - 4,4).getDisplayValues(); // This gets the values from D5 to the last row (minus 4, so we skip the header), and four columns (the whole table).
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Email"); // This tells the script we're going to use the file Email.html (which calls variables from this script)
  htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues = tableRangeValues;     // This "passes" the values from the script to the HTML template. 

  console.log("Content passed to HTML");

  var htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent(); // This "passes" the values back from the HTML template. 

  console.log("Content passed back from HTML");
  console.log("htmlForEmail = " + htmlForEmail);        // This logs the content of the htmlForEmail variable. 


// NOTE TO ADAM: MAKE THIS SECTION DYNAMIC


  var volunteer_emails=sheet.getRange(2,2,44,1).getDisplayValues(); // this gets the values from B2:B45 (the email addresses)

  console.log("Emails fetched");
  console.log("volunteer_emails are " + volunteer_emails);
  
  var sent_value = sheet.getRange("G4").getDisplayValue(); // This sees whether this week's email has been sent or not

/* 

This next section is a little intimidating. But, it's just using a IF-THEN-ELSE logic. If something is true, do X action. If it's not true (the "else") do Y action. 

*/


  if (sent_value === "Email_Sent"){                     // If the email HAS ALREADY been sent...
     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();                   // (Open the user interface)
     var result = ui.alert(                             // ... send an alert,
      "ERROR: Weekly Schedule for " + target_date + " is already marked 'Sent.'", // ... with this text,
      "Are you sure you would like to send it again?",
       ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);                            // ... and a "Yes" "No" option. 

     if (result == ui.Button.YES) {                     // If the user clicks "Yes"...
        MailApp.sendEmail({to: volunteer_emails.toString(),subject: target_date + ' - CPP Team Schedule',htmlBody: htmlForEmail}); //... send the email and
        });



       ui.alert("SUCCESS: Weekly Schedule for " + target_date + " has been sent.");    // ... send a confirmation alert.
     } else {                                           // If the user clicks "No"...
       ui.alert('NOTE: No reminder was sent.');                // ... send a cancellation alert.
     }                                                  // This closes the if-else statement

  } else {                                              // If the email HAS NOT YET been sent...
     MailApp.sendEmail({to: volunteer_emails.toString(),subject: target_date + ' - CPP Team Schedule',htmlBody: htmlForEmail}); //... send the email and
     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();                   // (Open the user interface)
     ui.alert("SUCCESS: Weekly Schedule for " + target_date + " has been sent."); // ... give a notification to the user, and
     var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sunday Team Schedule Current").getRange("A3:4"); // (This gets the first two lines for the Sunday Team Schedule Current.)
     var vs = rng.getDisplayValues();                   // (This gets the values from the range.)
     for (var j = 0; j < rng.getLastColumn(); j++) {    // (This searches the range for the target date)
       if (vs[0][j] == target_date) {                   // ... if a column = target_date, then... 
           SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sunday Team Schedule Current").getRange(4,1+j).setValue("Email_Sent"); // ... put "Email_Sent" in that column, "correcting" for the zero index. 
       }                                                // This closes the if.
     }                                                  // This closes the for.
  }                                                     // This closes the if (email sent)-else.
}                                                       // This closes the function.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>


    <div>

      <div style="height:4px">
        <table>
          <tbody>
              <? tableRangeValues.forEach(r => { ?> 
                <tr>
                  <td><?= r[0] ?></td><td><?= r[1] ?></td><td><?= r[2] ?></td><td><?= r[3] ?></td>
                </tr>
              <? }) ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, so I've learned more about this issue. My phone displays that same message no sweat. But alternate email accounts and alternate browsers still don't display the message. Maybe I've categorized this wrongly, and it's something native to desktop Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the `<div style="height:4px">` of your HTML file. The content height is greater than the div container height. Changing it to a bigger value or deleting the height attribute will fix the issue.

**Example:**

`<div style="height:4px">`:

[image]

`<div style="height:40px">`:

[image]

no height attribute:

[image]

Comment: You, Nikko, are a baller. I wasn't even looking in the right place. :)